# JiBX without ANT?

Tags: java, jibx

is there a way to use JiBX Databinder without Ant?

I dont have ant on my application server and when I want to run my mapping there I get Exceptions that the binding is not compiled.

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse to develop? If so, the [JiBX Eclipse plugin](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/eclipse/index.html) works pretty well. It "will automatically run the JiBX binding compiler whenever it detects a change that might effect the bindings or bound classes".

Comment: Thanks I will try, but is there a way to compile the binding from code? I know the JiBX has a Compile class.

Comment: I see. I haven't tried myself, but that looks like [Compile](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jibx/jibx-bind/1.2.3/jibx-bind-1.2.3-javadoc.jar!/org/jibx/binding/Compile.html) is a good option. An alternative could be to use [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to run the binding compiler as you would on the command line. [This page](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/bindcomp.html) might give you some other ideas. Good luck!